# How read in Delphi the domain connected user on a web application

Tags: multithreading, delphi, web

An application must read the domain user connected for to do something.
When the application is an exe file, it's all right. All functions (GetUserName, GetUserNameA, GetUserNameW and GetUserNameEx) returns correct value, but when the application is a web application, thats functions returns IUSR_(pc_name) user !!.
How read the real connected user (not the internet username) where navigator is running?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your webapplication, activate domain authentication on your webserver?

Comment: What's "navigator"? Where's it running?

Comment: You are fundamentally misunderstanding the difference between a web application and a desktop application. The web application will be run as a spawned process of whatever web server software you are running (I assume IIS judging by the user name you quoted) as a result of a request from a browser. This browser could be running on any device anywhere in the world. Your web server will run under a dedicated user account for the server which is why your calls to GetUserNamex are returning IUSER_xxx as your web app process runs under the same account as the web server software.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks. I've added an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are fundamentally misunderstanding the difference between a web application and a desktop application. The web application will be run as a spawned process of whatever web server software you are running (I assume IIS judging by the user name you quoted) as a result of a request from a browser. This browser could be running on any device anywhere in the world. Your web server will run under a dedicated user account for the server which is why your calls to GetUserNamex are returning IUSER_xxx as your web app process runs under the same account as the web server software.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm understanding the difference between both application kind.
The question is how running the exe file (ex. http://mydomain.com:8053 the port 8053 fires an exe file and run on navigator as a web application, Unigui application) when calling GetUserName returns the real connected user to the domain, but when the application runs as dll (http://mydomain.com/cgi-bin/myApplication.dll) when calling GetUserName returns the IUSR_(pcName) user... Perhaps read the user form a thread. How can I know who is real user connected (nor IUSR_(pcName)), is there another Windows API function similar to GetUserName?